# Error working with Typhoreus and SeoMoz API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, typhoeus

I am working with the SEOMoz API using the Typhoreus gem. To authenticate(Signed Authentication) with the API, I use the following code:

```
 url = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/"+website.url.strip+"?Cols=103079231520"

 response = Typhoeus::Request.get(url, :username => "member-xxxxxxx", :password => "abcxyzwhatever")



To which I get the error: Ethon::Errors::InvalidOption: The option: username is invalid.
Please try userpwd instead of username.
```

If I change the username to userpwd, it asks to change password to userpwd as well.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The api changed a bit, that should work:

```
Typhoeus::Request.get(url, :userpwd => "member-xxxxxxx:abcxyzwhatever")
```